# endnotes with eledmac

Tags: endnotes, eledmac

Here's a very minimal NWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}
\Aendnote{BBB}

\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I see in the log:

```
\Aend{}{}{BBB}{A}
! I can't find file `memoir-eledmac.end'.
\doendnotes ...me =\endprint \input \jobname .end 
                                                  \endgroup 
l.9 \doendnotes{A}
```

Could someone please help me turn this into a working example?

Comment: As tobi said, end notes will eledmac is to be used as critical endnotes, i. e. endnote associeted to lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\Aendnote` mut be in the second argument of `\edtext` which must be between `\pstart` and `\pend`, which must be between `\beginnumbering` and `\endnumbering`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{eledmac}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtext{lemma}{\Aendnote{BBB}}
\pend
\endnumbering

\doendnotes{A}
\end{document}
```

The reason is that `\Aendnote` is concered to set critical notes on some text (the lemma), which must be set in this way.

---

If you just want to have endnotes take a look at the [`endnotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endnotes) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\begin{document}
Text\endnote{BBB}

\theendnotes
\end{document}
```